# USB-Printer printing progress information

Tags: windows, printing, usb

I need to write a program that finds all connected USB-printers of a Windows PC and send a file to a selected printer from this list. These two points are no problem and work pretty fine

**First point**

```
        var printerQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
        i = 1;
        foreach (var printer in printerQuery.Get())
        {
            var name = printer.GetPropertyValue("Name");
            var status = printer.GetPropertyValue("Status");
            var isDefault = printer.GetPropertyValue("Default");
            var isNetworkPrinter = printer.GetPropertyValue("Network");
            var PortName = printer.GetPropertyValue("PortName");
            bool Connected = (bool)printer.GetPropertyValue("WorkOffline");
            var Caption = printer.GetPropertyValue("Caption");

            string s = "Name: " + name;
            string nbr = "";
            if (i.ToString().Length < 2) nbr = "0";
            nbr += i.ToString();
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add(nbr + ": " + s);
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Status: " + status);
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Default: " + isDefault);
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Network: " + isNetworkPrinter);
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      PortName: " + PortName);
            if ( Connected) listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Connected: True");
            if (!Connected) listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Connected: False");
            listBoxUSBInfo.Items.Add("      Caption: " + Caption);

            i++;
        }
```

**Second point**

Is quite easy:

The class "`RawPrinterHelper`" is well known in this forum, I think

```
RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter("PrinterName", "FileName");
```

**But now my problem.**

I must print very large files (more than 100.000 pages) and the operator wants to see, how many pages are currently printed. Is it possible to get this information? For example every 3 seconds, so that I can display at on the screen.

Here is some more information about the RawPrinterHelper Class. It contains no callback. **What must I do to define a callback Function?**

```
public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        fs.Close();
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
} // public class RawPrinterHelper
```

Comment: You may want to add language-appropriate tag.

Comment: If `RawPrinterHelper` doesn't support a callback to provide status info, you're most likely out of luck.

Comment: The problen above must be solved in C#.